# xcode - warning there's no getter/setter for property not even mentioned in the code!

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface, interface-builder

I got the warning :

> property 'textField' requires method
>   '-textField' to be defined - use
>   @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a
>   method implementation.

Now, there is no such property defined in my project! More bizarre, if I just click save in Interface builder and build again, the build is successful - though, right on the line with '@end' the warning appears. Also weird: if I begin to write some code ..and then  delete it just the way it was before writing it (maybe not code..anything) and then build&go the warning with the textField appears again. Could be a bug of sdk? What could be happening?

Comment: What class is your class subclassing?

Comment: I solved it. My project was using a class from an older project (i dragged it in xcode). Wthat textField was defined in the old class but later i removed it from IB. So my project wasn't using my WebViewController from my project, but WebViewController from an older project. What is strange is that the class present in my project was not the one in use, but the one from the older project.

Comment: The warning doesn't appear every time because XCode won't recompile your source file if it doesn't need to.  When you make changes, XCode recompiles.

Answer (score 0):

Go into interface builder, and click File > Read all class files.  Save and quit IB.  Go back into Xcode and click Build > Build & Clean.  Build your project.